Arabic text is only recognized as the exact original text in Interactive mode
$Text  = 'مرحبا يا عالم'
$TextR = -Join ($Text.ToCharArray() | Sort {(--$script:i)})
$Text; $TextR; sleep 5

I have a little problem.
Arabic text is not recognized as the exact original text in Non-Interactive Mode
When I copy-paste the contents of the script into the console (Interactive-mode) of PowerShell 5, the text is recognized and displays the same as the original text properly.
The Output:
ملاع اي ابحرم
مرحبا يا عالم

But, when I run the script directly from the file (Non-Interactive mode) in PowerShell 5, the text changes to other characters.
The Output:
Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ ÙŠØ§ Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…
…Ù„Ù§Ø¹Ø §ØŠÙ §Ø¨Ø­Ø±Ø…Ù

I have been and still looking for a solution...
I thank you very much for the solution

Basically, I am making an assignment to create a script containing Arabic text and giving it to the students.
I have to make sure the script can be executed and read properly by them.

Since the problem occurs with string literals in your source code, the likeliest explanation is that your script file is misinterpreted by the Windows PowerShell engine, which happens if the script is saved as UTF-8 without a BOM (this is no longer a problem in PowerShell (Core) 7). Try saving your script as UTF-8 with BOM.
See the linked duplicate for details.

-@mklement0  Why don't I use pwsh? The problem is I have to use Powershell 5 (not pwsh). Since it's built into Windows, it's definitely present in all Windows, not pwsh. The Script for all students

About BOM, i will learn it. Thanks.

-@mklement0 Thank You. Based on your suggestion link, the problem solved. I just found out this trick.

You face a mojibake case (example in Python for its universal intelligibility): print('مرحبا يا عالم'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252', errors='ignore')) returns Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ ÙŠØ§ Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…. In terms of PowerShell: [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetBytes( 'مرحبا يا عالم')) returns Ù…Ø±Ø­Ø¨Ø§ ÙŠØ§ Ø¹Ø§Ù„Ù…. Check [System.Console]::InputEncoding; [System.Console]::OutputEncoding (try  [System.Console]::InputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8).

@JosefZ: The only fix is needed is to save the source-code file (.ps1) as UTF-8 with BOM, so that the Windows PowerShell engine recognizes it as UTF-8-encoded - no need for changes to [System.Console]::InputEncoding and [System.Console]::OutputEncoding, which only matter when it comes to communicating with external programs
